# How to make clear in a constructor, that an object can be inserted as well as all subclasses of that object?

Tags: java, constructor

I'm trying to make it possible to initiate an instance of the class Function like this.

```
Function chain = new CosineFunction(new SquareRootFunction(new SineFunction()));
```

This is the code for the super-class `Function`

```
public class Function {
    
    private Function innerFunction;
    
    public Function() {
        
    }
    
    public Function(Function innerFunction) {
        this.innerFunction = innerFunction;
    }
    
    public double calculate(double value) {
        if(innerFunction != null) {
            return innerFunction.calculate(value);
        } else {
            return this.formula(value);
        }
    }
    
    protected double formula(double value) {
        return value;
    }

    public Function getInnerFunction() {
        return innerFunction;
    }

    public void setInnerFunction(Function innerFunction) {
        this.innerFunction = innerFunction;
    }
}
```

Any other class with "function" at the end of the name is a subclass of `Function`. The only `@Override` is the `protected double formula(double value)`.

If I try to initiate a chain, I get an error saying:

> The constructor CosineFunction(SquareRootFunction) is undefined

How do I make clear, that all subclasses of `Function` are also allowed in the constructor?

Comment: Your problem is with the constructor of `CosineFunction`, so you need to show your code of `CosineFunction`. Constructors aren't inherited, so you need to define the proper constructor in each subclass.

Comment: As a workaround, it should be possible to define a method `of(Function f) {setInnerFunction(f); return this;}` in `Function` and then use that as `new CosineFunction().of(new SquareRootFunction().of(new SineFunction()))`. Downside is that `innerFunction` can not be `final`, but right now it's not anyway (but probably should be).

Comment: Ah, i did not know that constructors are not inherited, thank you